# lumen execute apidoc generator

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen

**When I generate apidoc-generator in my lumen project**

In ApiDocGeneratorServiceProvider.php line 27:
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::configPath()

how to resolve this?

Comment: Your question is vague , please ask your question explicitly

Comment: I want to generate the documentation for  Lumen  with the command,
php artisan apidoc:generate

Then I have error message above this.
Now I think my question is clear.

Comment: hey @prabodha, that package isn't maintained anymore. You should use this: https://github.com/knuckleswtf/scribe

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best work around but I was able to solve the problem by manually editing the **ApiDocGeneratorServiceProvider.php** file in the ***vendor/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator/src/*** directory. On line 27 change

`$this->app->configPath('apidoc.php'),`
to
`$this->app->basePath('config/apidoc.php')`.

This error arises due to the fact that `configPath()` is not included as helper function in Lumen v5.* up until v6. Hope this helps.